# Al pasar el mouse por encima del botón, la flecha se anima correctamente, pero al quitar el mouse, el regreso de la flecha se hace de manera brusca

Tags: css, transition

Tengo un botón similar al del código, que al clickear en él (se agrega o remueve la clase `.active`, cosa que en el editor de código de SO no sucede, por lo que reemplacé `.active` por `:hover`) yo quiero que la "flechita" que está al principio gire para abajo, o vuelva a apuntar hacia la derecha.

La cosa es que, como verán, al pasar el mouse por encima del botón, la flecha se anima y gira correctamente, pero al quitar el mouse, el regreso de la flecha se hace de manera brusca.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Dónde o de qué manera debería colocar la *transition* para que se aprecie correctamente cuando la flecha gira de abajo hacia la derecha?

```css
.titulo-item::before{
    content: '> ';
    font-weight: 700;
    transition: .3s ease all;
}

.titulo-item:hover::before{
    display:inline-block;
    transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
    transition: .3s ease all;
}

.titulo-item{
    cursor:pointer ;
    padding: 1rem 0rem;
    border:none;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    transition: .3s ease all;
    outline:none;
}
```

```html
  <button class="collapsible titulo-item">
                           Soy un boton
  </button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El `display: inline-block` es lo que te esta rompiendo la transición cuando pierde el `hover`, ponlo en el `::before`.

El `transition` solo debería estar en el `::before`

```css
.titulo-item::before{
    content: '> ';
    font-weight: 700;
    transition: .3s ease all;
    display:inline-block;
}

.titulo-item:hover::before{
    transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
}

.titulo-item{
    cursor:pointer ;
    padding: 1rem 0rem;
    border:none;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    transition: .3s ease all;
    outline:none;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible titulo-item">
                           Soy un boton
  </button>
```